# How can a titration help me figure out the effect of rosmarinic acid on amylase activity?

Tags: titration

So with my limited knowledge of rosmarinic acid, I am aware that it is an non-competitive inhibitor and can inhibit the enzyme, amylase. When starch is added to a solution of already mixed rosmarinic acid and amylase, it doesn’t break down due to the inhibition.

A titration was used to investigate the effect of rosmarinic acid on amylase. The solution containing the rosmarinic acid was put into a burette and was the titrant for this experiment whilst the potassium permanganate was the titrate.

I have a few questions about this experiment. Why was a titration used and how could it identify if the rosmarinic did have an effect on the amylase? Also, why was the solution containing rosmarinic acid the titrant instead of the titrate? What is the potassium permanganate’s role in this investigation?

Comment: Do you have a link to the experimental protocol? I have a few thoughts: 1. RA is easily oxidized, say by permanganate; 2. reducible sugar is also oxidized by permanganate; 3. RA interferes with conversion of starch to glucose; 4. pink/violet permanganate is reduced to colorless Mn2+ in acidic solution.